# Jquery .load() not working properly

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spfx-webparts, reactjs

I am building a react spfx solution that looks like a website. It has a nav bar. The navbar is actually links to the site pages in the same site. What I need is load the contents from "spPageCanvasContent" of the selected nav link to my home page. I tried to do it using Jquery .load() method. it does load the content but somehow replace my entire homepage. I am working on sharepoint online. Has anyone face this issue before. Please help

```
$("#articleContent").load("<siteUrl>/SitePages/Home.aspx#digitalDownload");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is doesn't directly answer your question, but I think it's important enough to put as an answer rather than a comment.

As stated in [SharePoint Framework enterprise guidance | In perspective: SharePoint Framework in the broader SharePoint platform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/enterprise-guidance#in-perspective-sharepoint-framework-in-the-broader-sharepoint-platform):

> The SharePoint page HTML DOM is not an API. You should avoid taking
> any dependencies on the page DOM structure or CSS styles, which are
> subject to change and potentially break your solutions. SharePoint
> Framework provides a rich API to customize the SharePoint experience
> in reliable ways and is the only supported means to interact with the
> SharePoint page HTML DOM.

The practice of querying or manipulating the page DOM, which was common in classic SharePoint, is strongly discouraged in modern SharePoint. Code that takes dependencies on the page DOM structure or CSS styles in modern pages will eventually break, it's just a matter of how frequently it will happen.